# Why Member Function find() Missing On One Script But Not The Other?

Tags: php, oop, dom, web-crawler

Php Experts,

This script works:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php'); 

$html = file_get_html('http://google.com'); 

//to fetch all hyperlinks from a webpage 
$links = array(); 
foreach($html->find('a') as $a) { 
$links[] = $a->href; 
} 
print_r($links); 
echo "<br />"; 

//to fetch all images from a webpage 
$images = array(); 
foreach($html->find('img') as $img) { 
$images[] = $img->src; 
} 
print_r($images); 
echo "<br />"; 

//to find h1 headers from a webpage 
$headlines = array(); 
foreach($html->find('h1') as $header) { 
$headlines[] = $header->plaintext; 
} 
print_r($headlines); 
echo "<br />"; 

?>
```

I get no error that the "find" is not recognized.
But, why do I get that error on this following modifications of mine ?

```
<?php  

/* FINDING HTML ELEMENTS BASED ON THEIR TAG NAMES 

Suppose you wanted to find each and every link on a webpage.  
We will be using “find” function to extract this information from the 
object. Here’s how to do it using Simple HTML DOM Parser : 
*/ 

include('simple_html_dom.php'); 

$url = 'https://www.yahoo.com'; 
$curl = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
$html = curl_exec($curl); 

//to fetch all hyperlinks from a webpage 
$links = array(); 
foreach($html->find('a') as $a) { 
$links[] = $a->href; 
} 
print_r($links); 
echo "<br />"; 

?>
```

I get error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\cURL\crawler.php:24 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\cURL\crawler.php on line 24

Strange! How come I don't get this same error regarding the "find" on the first script that works ? Very strange!
Both scripts are nearly the same. On my modified version I just replaced the "$html = file_get_html('');" with cURL. See for yourselves.

The simple_html_dom.php file can be downloaded from here:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/
I put this dom file in the same directory as the script file.
This means, I just replaced:

```
//$html = file_get_html('http://nimishprabhu.com');
```

with:

```
$url = 'https://www.yahoo.com'; 
$curl = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
$html = curl_exec($curl);
```

That is all!

1st EDIT:
u_mulder's code is working on some urls but not on yahoo. Why is that ?

```
$url = 'https://www.yahoo.com'; 
$curl = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
$response_string = curl_exec($curl); 

$html = str_get_html($response_string);

//to fetch all hyperlinks from a webpage 
$links = array(); 
foreach($html->find('a') as $a) { 
    $links[] = $a->href; 
} 
print_r($links); 
echo "<br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `file_get_html` is a special function from `simple_html_dom` library. 
If you open source code for `simple_html_dom` you will see that `file_get_html()` **does** a lot of things that your `curl` replacement **does not**. That's why you get your error.

Possible solution with `str_get_html`:

```
$url = 'https://www.yahoo.com'; 
$curl = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
$response_string = curl_exec($curl); 

$html = str_get_html($response_string);

//to fetch all hyperlinks from a webpage 
$links = array(); 
foreach($html->find('a') as $a) { 
    $links[] = $a->href; 
} 
print_r($links); 
echo "<br />";
```

Comment: u_mulder,
Mmm. That makes sense now! Thanks!
But, any chance you can fix it with cURL ? I'm still learning cURL and php. A beginner in php, if you really must know. But, that is not stopping me from trying to build my own simple web crawler!

Comment: You can use `str_get_html` and pass your curl result as an argument.

Comment: Just one question U_mulder,

That script of our's works on:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50438356/why-member-function-find-missing-on-one-script-but-not-the-other

But try fetching https://yahoo.com and you'd see an empty array as the result. Why is our script failing to extract links off of Yahoo Homepage ? This is now a hit & miss result. Let's turn it around into a hit for all pages no matter what the page.

Comment: I have changed my original post by adding the section at the bottom:
"1st EDIT".